# How to make Ubuntu 18.04 Dock look like 16.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, dock, ubuntu-dock

As the title says, I want my dock to look like Ubuntu 16.04 Dock.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 uses the Unity Desktop Environment, whereas 18.04 currently uses Gnome 3.28.1. To install Unity on Ubuntu 18.04, open terminal and type `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop`. You will be given a choice between display managers. LightDM is the Default Display manager for the Unity desktop, but either choice should work.

Take a look at [this link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-unity-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) for a detailed explanation. Also look at [NoobsLab](https://noobslab.com) If you want the dock icons changed without installing an entire Desktop Environment. Various Gnome Shell Extentions such as Dash to Dock also allow for lots of customization.